# I have a 1024x1024 png i want to split it into 64x64 (256 equal parts)

Tags: image-manipulation

I have a 1024x1024 png i want to split it into 64x64 (256 equal parts)

i found a program that can do this but it's not free it's called "Split and Tile"

i would like to find out a free way to do this.

Comment: Are you looking to achieve this programmatically, or are you just looking for a freeware alternative that'll do this for you?

Comment: I think this question should be asked on SuperUser.

Comment: @oded funny, @others detunized answer was sufficeint

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) could do that for you with a simple one-liner:

```
convert -crop 64x64 source.png tile%d.png
```

Comment: Just FYI, if you want to break it up into a certain number of tiles and not need to calculate the exact pixels required you can do the following:

"convert -crop 3x3@  source.png tile_%d.png"

This would break up the source image into 9 equal tiles

Comment: Anyone know how to make it split with a number for row and a number for column?

Answer (score 2):

http://arje.net/rasterbator and  http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/" do not work. I have tried it. You may try Online [image spliter](http://imagesplitter.net/).

Here, I will guide you how to upload and split your image in the website, since it is a bit tricky. Upload your image by clicking picture icon close to <kbd>upload image</kbd>.

Next, hit <kbd>upload image</kbd> and wait your image to be uploaded to the website.

At the upper center position you will now see  a text <kbd>split image</kbd>. Look at the left side, you will see row and column. Adjust row and column as you need.

After you hit <kbd>split image</kbd> your picture will be automatically downloaded.

Comment: The issue with this, is that it expect "paper" dimensions. Not digital ones. It assumes mm's and not pixels. Doesn't help people working in all digital design.