# How split a large image so it will display in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have been trying to find a solution to this for a while. I have a large panoramic image that I want to load into a game in cocos2d, but it is too large to load.

I know I need to split the image up into tiles but Im not sure how. I tried doing a setTextureRect but that only works on smaller files and still wont let me load larger files.

Any advice or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display only some part of image? What is the size of that image?

Comment: if the image is greater than 4096 (on some devices only 2048) pixels in any direction you'll have to split it with an image program

Comment: The image is taken from the camera roll and comes out at 16000 * 4000 pixels. I want to display the entire image but have seen other people saying it has to be split and added as several images, poss using spriteAtlas.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an image splitting program. I recommend using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to accomplish this, but you can find alternatives and information on how to use ImageMagick in  [this Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761365/i-have-a-1024x1024-png-i-want-to-split-it-into-64x64-256-equal-parts) From there, you'll want to create a texture atlas with the images, which again you need software for. I'd recommend using [Zwoptex](http://www.zwopple.com/zwoptex/), but again, [here's a great list of alternatives and other software.](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/texture-atlas/)

Good luck!